# If launch first android auto this don’t show tracks

Tags: flutter, android-auto, audio-service

Hello do u know why if I connect the smartphone to the car radio, if I don't open the app before and open directly the android auto, this show me an empty list and then when I open the app stuck on launch screen?

Comment: Is this related to Flutter? Can you provide more info?

Comment: @SujanGainju 
Of course. I basically use the audio_service plugin configured as per the example app in the original repository. My songs are shown so you Android car and I can only play them if before launching the app on Android car first booting from the phone. Otherwise, if I do not start the app from the phone and start it directly from Android auto (in the car) the songs are not shown and if then after launching the app remains stuck on the launch-screen

Answer (score -1):

Solved by passing myGetSongs() method inside init() of audio service